# What is the variation of Gauss-Bonnet term a total derivative of?

Tags: general-relativity, curvature

What is the variation of [Gauss-Bonnet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Bonnet_gravity) term total derivative of?

i.e. Variation of Gauss-Bonnet combination $= \nabla_{\mu} C^{\mu}$.

What's $C^{\mu}$ in 4-dimensions?

Comment: A fairly careful and recent discussion of this can be found here: https://arxiv.org/abs/1008.5154v1. They discuss this using the language of forms (where the result has been known for a long time), and using just functions of the metric.

Answer (score 4):

If you just want to know why the Gauss-Bonnet Term is topological, you should take a look at [the  generalized gauss bonet theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_Gauss%E2%80%93Bonnet_theorem).

The integral over the gauss-bonet term is proportional to the euler-characteristic, which is a topological invariant, so it can't contribute to the dynamics.

Comment: Your last sentence isn't necessarily true. It assumes that the variation of the Euler Characteristic has to vanish.There is nothing forbidding topological change in general relativity and indeed the formation of a black hole may be evidence of such. Check out this interesting paper by Gibbons and Hawking where they suggest changes in topology have to have selection rules (occur in pairs!) https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~v1ranick/papers/gibhaw2.pdf

Answer (score 3):

According to [this website](http://relativity.livingreviews.org/open?pubNo=lrr-2010-3&page=articlese12.html),
for a four dimensional manifold,
$$
G = \nabla_{\alpha}J^{\alpha},
$$
where
$$
G = R^2 -4 R_{\alpha \beta} R^{\alpha \beta}
+ R_{\alpha \beta \gamma \delta}R^{\alpha \beta \gamma \delta},
$$
and
$$
J^{\alpha} = \epsilon^{\alpha \beta \gamma \delta} \epsilon_{\rho \sigma}^{\;\;\; \mu \nu}
\Gamma^{\rho}_{\;\; \mu \beta}
\left[
\frac{1}{2} R^{\sigma}_{\;\; \nu \gamma \delta}
+ \frac{1}{3} \Gamma^{\sigma}_{\;\; \lambda \gamma} \Gamma^{\lambda}_{\;\; \nu \sigma}
\right].
$$
So $G$ becomes a topological term in the action, which does not contribute to the dynamics.
However, I have yet to check it myself...

Comment: The link is now broken, and I've been unable to find the Living Review that mentions this result. Could you update the link? Thanks!

Comment: A nice discussion of writing the Lanczos-Lovelock Lagrangians as total derivatives can be found here: https://arxiv.org/abs/1008.5154v1. In this article they also provide a fairly careful discussion as to why the equation you're quoting is incorrect for general metrics.